# clear textview on update

Tags: java, android, oop

In my application I have a Spinner which shoots various https request and request for string of data. I use TextView.append() to display a set of String in the TextView. I want to clear the textview and update it with new text when new item is selected from Spinner and update the TextView with new set of String and clear the previously displayed data.

```
for (int m = 0; m < topTenUsers.size(); m++) {
users = topTenUsers.get(m).getString("fullName") + "\n";
toptenusers.append(users);
}
```

Can you tell me how to clear textzView everytime Spinner option is changed

Answer (score 0):

To clear a `TextView`, do something like:

```
textview.setText("");
```

You could also simply use:

```
textview.setText(users);
```

this way you will not have to clear it every time.

Comment: Kahre that only sets the View to "" but the TextView still holds the previous data

Comment: What do you mean _still holds_ the previous data? Where does it hold it? What is the visual outcome?

Comment: it holds the previous data in TextView Buffer. It appends new data to to previous data and not clears it

Comment: It sounds like the TextView text is inherently bound to users?  Doesn't users need to be cleared first before updating the text view?  Like, store the users into a tmp variable, then clear users, then reassign the new users to that tmp variable.

Comment: @Shaz I think the problem is what RichS mentions. The problem maybe with `users` variable. You could post more code to make your question more clear.